# typescript and breeze module cannot be aliased by a non module type

Tags: typescript, breeze

import breeze=module(Breeze) is giving me the following error:
module cannot be aliased by a non module type

```
    /// <reference path="../typings/breeze.d.ts" />

export module DataContext {

     import breeze = module(Breeze);
    export class FileStructure {
        private EntityQuery: breeze.EntityQuery;
        private Manager: breeze.EntityManager;

        constructor(MainController: string) {
            //validate the format api/BreezeController/
            this.EntityQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery;
            this.Manager = this.configureBreezeManager(MainController);
        }
        private configureBreezeManager(MainController: string) {
            breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
            return new breeze.EntityManager(MainController);
        }
        public getAllFileStructures()
        {
            //define the query
            var query =
                this.EntityQuery
                .from('FileStructure')
                .using(this.Manager).execute()
                .then(this.querySucceeeded)
                .fail(this.queryFailed);
            return query;
        }

        //define the promises and how they will behave once a query its executed.
        private querySucceeeded(data) {
            return data.results;
        }
        private queryFailed(error) {
           //
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: import = module statement without quotes refer to "internal" modules, while those with quotes are "external" modules.  AMD modules are "external" modules and thus will require quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `import breeze = module(Breeze);` should be `import breeze = module('path_to_breeze_module');` where the path to the breeze module is relative to the root of your app.

This will only work if breeze is packaged as an AMD module which is, I think, unusual: otherwise you can just remove the `import` line altogether and simply include breeze in a `<script/>` anywhere before you load your first AMD module (presumably with require.js or similar).

Comment: I just want import breeze=module(Breeze) to compile to var breeze = Breeze;

Comment: I see! I would need durandal or something huh. Otherwise, I have to load it manually for it to have the dependencies right?

Comment: Yes, by include breeze I mean breeze.js

Comment: I had breeze.debug.js changed it to breeze.js and removed import breeze = module(Breeze); Done.

Answer (score 4):

You can change import as

```
import breeze = require ("../typings/breeze");
```

Please be sure that in breeze.d.ts module is defined as

```
export module Breeze {
.
.
```

Also be sure that you have removed `///<require for breeze />` statement where you put import statement.

PS: import.. = module(...) has changed to import ..= requre(..) in newer typescript versions.